# Which of the five conformers of propyl propanoate is most stable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

I've worked out five different conformations of propyl propanoate:

[image]

I think the bisected conformations (E) should be the most stable one.

Are my rationals and suggestions in my scheme correct?

Comment: Your basic arguments seem fine to me.  Certainly the s-trans conformations are higher energy than the s-cis conformations (like E), see [here](http://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/local/organic/conf/c1_unsat.html) for a nice explanation.  As to whether B or E is favored, I think they are very close in energy, but if I had to pick just one, then I'd choose E.  A few minor points, 1) there are 8 expected low-energy conformations, you've only drawn 5, 2) stereochemistry in the ethyl group is not properly displayed in C and D (you show both a methyl and a hydrogen in the plane), but I understand what you mean.